# I would like to backup file x before its deleted in android

Tags: java, android, reflection, fileobserver

I would like to backup file x before its deleted .
With FileObserver I would just get information that file was
deleted ... Is it possible to access file just before event occur ,
like just before deleting its create back up in my sdcard and other thing move to sdcard?
i want similarly app like dumpster-recycle bin in android. or is it possible i can change delete file behavior to move file in android plz give me solution i am new in android and file observer not correctly understanding.

thanks in advance....